# Print arbitrary set of images at runtime with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's assume a bunch of images are preloaded via something like this:

```
function loadNextImage() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '/path/to/imageN.jpg';
    img.onload = function() {
        if(stillLoading()) {
            loadNextImage();
        } else {
            printLoadedImages();
        }
    }
}
```

What can be used for printLoadedImages() to make them print (ultimately as a series- one per page, but for starters let's just say one image)

When I try setting the image source to a div, I can see the image- but trying printThis or printArea jquery plugins did not do it... seems to expect that the image was loaded via page load, not at runtime

Comment: where have defined `stillLoading` variable?

Comment: Not sure why that matters, but edited to make it a function instead, which we can imagine checks if all the required images are loaded

Comment: To force each image to be printed on a separate page you can set the CSS property 'page break after' to 'always': CSS: `page-break-after: always;` JS: `elem.style.pageBreakAfter = 'always';`

Comment: Thanks B0Andrew- great piece of info, will keep that in mind for once I get the first image printing :)